# Efficient way to query records greater than 10k in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to query a table based on certain input parameters.
Due to constant increase in the number of records findby method is gradually taking more time to execute which is causing an exception during runtime.

What is the best way to fine tune and query huge records in a shot? Any help would be appreciated.

Repo:

```
   @Query("SELECT ap FROM AP ap WHERE ap.workCentre = :workCentre "
        + "AND ap.lastUpdated>:lastUpdated "
        + "AND ap.stagingIndicator>1 "
        + "AND (ap.productCode='XYA' OR ap.productCode='ABC')")
List<AP> findAPByStationAndLastUpdated(@Param("wc") Integer wc, @Param("lastUpdated") Date lastUpdated);
```

Entity:

```
public class AP implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    

    @OneToOne(optional = false,  fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sk", referencedColumnName = "sk")
    private AStop aStop;
}
```

Comment: I know it may sound like a dumb question, but are there any indexes in your table? I mean, from my perspective, this isn't a complex query with lots of joins, so I think this should be running in a appropriate time, even if you're working with hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: Can you clarify whether 10k is the number of rows in the table, or the number of rows retrieved by the query? Also, *how much* time is the query taking? *Which* exception is being thrown?

Comment: Also, your query refers to fields not declared by your entity, what's with that?

Comment: @meriton Currently, it is the number of rows returned by the query. I have removed other fields just to keep it short. As of now it's taking 70-80s to query 10k records.

Answer (score 1):

With large data, processing it as a stream is the best, and usually only, way.

Instead of returning `List<>`, return `Stream<>`:

```
@Query("SELECT ap FROM AP ap WHERE ap.workCentre = :workCentre "
        + "AND ap.lastUpdated>:lastUpdated "
        + "AND ap.stagingIndicator>1 "
        + "AND (ap.productCode='XYA' OR ap.productCode='ABC')")
Stream<AP> findAPByStationAndLastUpdated(@Param("wc") Integer wc, @Param("lastUpdated") Date lastUpdated);
```

---

Example usage:

```
findAPByStationAndLastUpdated(someInt, someDate).forEach(this:processAp);
```

with:

```
private void processAp(AP ap) {
    // do something with ap
}
```

Comment: Are 10k rows "large"? If we assume 100 bytes per entity, that's only 1 MB of memory.

Comment: @meriton It's not a large dataset but it is taking 79s of time on an avg.

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks for the help. Stream does not helped me. Still it's taking the same amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

> As of now it's taking 70-80s to query 10k records

Unless these records are huge (due to containing large CLOB or BLOB that are eagerly loaded, or referencing other entities that are eagerly loaded), that delay is not JPA, but the database.

You should therefore do the usual troubleshooting steps for slow queries: Check that you have created appropriate indices in the database, look at an explain plan to see what the database is doing, or have its management console suggest better indices.

Judging from the query, an index like

```
create index on AP(workcentre, productcode, lastupdated, stagingindicator, and, then, all, remaining, columns)
```

or, if the stagingindicator has few different values,

```
create index on AP(workcentre, productcode, stagingindicator, lastupdated, and, then, all, remaining, columns)
```

should be ideal and allow for the query to run in a fraction of a second (by allowing the database to satisfy the query with a couple of index range scans).